GeoProjection - Spilhaus Projection of 1942 or Adam Square II
How can I make a GeoProjection like this?

The best I could get was:
GeoGraphics["World", GeoBackground -> "StreetMapNoLabels", GeoProjection -> {"ObliqueMercator", {"Centering" -> {{149, -180},-40}}}, GeoGridLines -> Automatic, GeoGridLinesStyle -> Directive[White, Opacity[0.25]]]



More information on the projection from D3.js. And from here, it seems to be equivalent to The Adam Square II projection.
Geographic Coordinate System: GCS WGS 1984
Projection: Adams Square II
False Easting: 0 m
False Northing: 0 m
Scale Factor: 1
Azimuth: 40.17823482°
Longitude of Center: 66.94970198°E
Latitude of Center: 49.56371678°S
XY Plane Rotation: 45°


Why are continents mirrored in your output? Should it be this way?

No - continents should not be mirrored. I'll investigate why,

GeoGraphics["World", GeoBackground -> "StreetMapNoLabels",   GeoProjection -> "AzimuthalEquidistant", GeoGridLines -> Automatic,   GeoGridLinesStyle -> Directive[White, Opacity[0.25]],   GeoCenter -> GeoPosition[{-90, 60}]] is better than yours.

Unfortunately, I don't think you can accurately reproduce this image with the projections that are currently implemented in Mathematica (version 14.0). However, with some fiddling, we can implement a new projection (code attached at the bottom).
As you have already pointed out, the Spilhaus projection is in fact a variation on the Adams square II projection with some additional rotations.
Adams square II projection
Adams square II projection is a type of conformal (spherical) projection, which can be derived1 using the Schwarz-Christoffel formula in the complex plane. Geographic coordinates are represented as
$$\zeta =  p + i \lambda,$$
where $\lambda$ is the geographic longitude and $p = \operatorname{gd}^{-1}(\phi)$ is the isometric latitude with $\phi$ being the geographic latitude and $\operatorname{gd}$ the Gudermannian function.
The projected coordinates are represented as $w = x + iy$.
The relation between the coordinates is:
$$\operatorname{sd}\left(\sqrt2 w \bigg| \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = \sqrt2 i \tanh \frac{\overline{\zeta}}{4},$$
where $\operatorname{sd}$ is the Jacobi elliptic function. The forward and inverse transformations are therefore:
$$w = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\text{sd}^{-1}\left(i \sqrt{2} \tanh \left(\frac{\zeta ^*}{4}\right)\bigg|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right),$$
$$\overline{\zeta} = - 4 i \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\text{sd}\left(\sqrt{2} w\bigg|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right).$$
GeoGraphics["World", GeoProjection -> "AdamsSquareII", 
 GeoGridLines -> Automatic, GeoRangePadding -> None]


Spilhaus projection
To get the Spilhaus projection from the Adams square II, we need a 3D roll-pitch-yaw rotation of the geographic coordinates, and then the final $45^\circ$ rotation of the projected coordinates. All of the rotations have been implemented in the Adams square projection with the "Centering" parameter, so we just need to set the correct angles.
spilhausParameters = {{49.56, -66.95}, 40.18, 45};
GeoGraphics["World", GeoProjection -> {"AdamsSquareII", 
 {"Centering" -> spilhausParameters}}, GeoGridLines -> Automatic]


Indeed, we get the identical map as the one in ArcGIS. The sampling of GeoGridLines is a bit coarse, so they don't go all the way to the corners.
Now we only have to play around with the styling to get a similar result. Unfortunately, it seems that these conformal projections don't work very well with vector maps (see for example the artifacts in GeoGraphics["World", GeoBackground -> "CountryBorders", GeoProjection -> "ObliqueMercatorNGS"]), because the polygons are not correctly clipped at the boundaries, so we are left with using the raster maps.
oceanColor = RGBColor @@ ({93, 182, 179}/255);
landColor = White;
imageSize = 800;

imgMap = Rasterize[GeoGraphics["World", 
    GeoProjection -> {"AdamsSquareII", {"Centering" -> 
        spilhausParameters}}, GeoBackground -> "VectorMonochrome", 
    Method -> {"VectorMapRemoveLabels" -> True}, 
    ImageSize -> imageSize]];
imgGridlines = Rasterize[GeoGraphics["World", 
    GeoProjection -> {"AdamsSquareII", {"Centering" -> 
        spilhausParameters}}, GeoBackground -> None, 
    GeoGridLines -> {18, 36}, GeoGridLines -> 10, 
    GeoGridLinesStyle -> Darker[oceanColor, 0.1], 
    ImageSize -> imageSize]];
imgLabels = Rasterize[GeoGraphics["World", 
    GeoProjection -> {"AdamsSquareII", {"Centering" -> 
        spilhausParameters}}, GeoBackground -> "VectorLabels", 
    ImageSize -> imageSize]];

{landColorOld, oceanColorOld} = DominantColors[imgMap];
img2 = ColorReplace[ColorNegate@
    DeleteSmallComponents[ColorNegate@ColorReplace[
       imgMap, {landColorOld -> landColor, oceanColorOld -> Black}], 
     2 imageSize], {Black -> oceanColor, White -> Black}];
img3 = ColorReplace[ImageMultiply[img2, imgGridlines], 
   Black -> landColor];
imgFinal = ImageMultiply[img3, ColorReplace[imgLabels, Black -> oceanColor, 0.4]]


As a final fun thing, we can reproduce this tiling, made by T. Jansen.
landColor = RGBColor[{34, 51, 68}/255];
oceanColor = RGBColor[{250, 248, 246}/255];
g = Graphics @@ GeoGraphics["World", GeoProjection -> "AdamsSquareII", 
    GeoBackground -> {"CountryBorders", "Land" -> landColor, 
      "Ocean" -> oceanColor, "Border" -> None}, 
    GeoGridLines -> Automatic, GeoGridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thin, landColor]];
Graphics[Table[Inset[g, i {1/2, 1/2} + j {1/2, -1/2}, Automatic, 
   1, {(-1)^i + (-1)^j, (-1)^j - (-1)^i}], {i, -3, 3}, {j, -3, 3}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 1}}]


Code for projection
GeoGraphics["World"];

BeginPackage["GIS`"];
Begin["`GeoProjectionsDump`"];
geoProjection[{"AdamsSquareII", "Spherical"}, {symbolicQ_, fail_}, {lambdadet_, phi0_, lambda0_, R_, k0_, fe_, fn_, gamma_, 
    omega_, rpyMat_, rpyMatInv_}] := geoFunction[
   {iphi, ilambda},
   Catch[
    geoModule[{dlambda, 
      w = Complex[0., 0.], ζ = Complex[0., 0.], phi = iphi, 
      lambda = ilambda, p = 0., x = 0., y = 0., z = 0.},
     (* RollPitchYaw rotation *)
     lambda = ilambda + lambda0;
     If[phi0 != 0 || gamma != 0,
      x = Cos[lambda] Cos[phi];
      y = Sin[lambda] Cos[phi];
      z = Sin[phi];
      {x, y, z} = rpyMat . {x, y, z};
      {lambda, phi} = {ArcTan[x, y], ArcSin[z/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]]}
      ];
     
     p = InverseGudermannian[phi];
     ζ = p + I lambda;
     w = InverseJacobiSD[I Sqrt[2] Tanh[Conjugate[ζ]/4], 1/2]/Sqrt[2];
      
     (* XY rotation *)
     w *= Exp[-I omega];
     
     {x, y} = {Re[w], Im[w]};
     ((R * k0) * {x, y}) + {fe, fn}
     ]
    ]
   ];
geoProjectionInverse[{"AdamsSquareII", "Spherical"}, {symbolicQ_, 
    fail_}, {lambdadet_, phi0_, lambda0_, R_, k0_, fe_, fn_, gamma_, 
    omega_, rpyMat_, rpyMatInv_}] := 
  geoFunction[{x0, y0}, 
   Catch[geoModule[{x = (x0 - fe)/(R k0), y = (y0 - fn)/(R k0), 
      z = 0., w = Complex[0.`, 0.`], ζ = Complex[0., 0.], 
      phi = 0.`, lambda = 0.`, p = 0., iphi = 0., ilambda = 0.},
     w = x + I y;
     
     (* XY rotation *)
     w *= Exp[I omega];
     
     ζ = 4 I Conjugate[ArcTan[JacobiSD[Sqrt[2] w, 1/2]/Sqrt[2]]];
     {p, lambda} = {Re[ζ], Im[ζ]};
     phi = Gudermannian[p];
     
     (* RollPitchYaw rotation *)
     If[phi0 != 0 || gamma != 0,
      x = Cos[lambda] Cos[phi];
      y = Sin[lambda] Cos[phi];
      z = Sin[phi];
      {x, y, z} = rpyMatInv . {x, y, z};
      {lambda, phi} = {ArcTan[x, y] - lambda0, 
        ArcSin[z/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]]}
      ];
     {phi, lambda}
     ]]];

geoProjectionInitialize[{"AdamsSquareII", "Spherical"}, opts___] := Module[
   {pao, obliq, georange, lambdadet, phi0, lambda0, R, k0, fe, fn, 
    gamma, omega, rpyMat, rpyMatInv},
   pao = 
    ParseGeoProjectionOptions[{"AdamsSquareII", 
      "Spherical"}, {"Obliqueness", "GeoRange", 
      "LongitudeDetermination", "CenteringLatitude", 
      "CenteringLongitude", "ReferenceModel", "CentralScaleFactor", 
      "GridOriginE", "GridOriginN", "Azimuth", "Tilting"}, opts];
   If[SameQ[pao, $Failed],
Throw[$Failed, "ProjectionInitializeError"]
    ];
   {obliq, georange, lambdadet, phi0, lambda0, R, k0, fe, fn, gamma, 
     omega} = pao ;
   rpyMat = RollPitchYawMatrix[{0, -phi0, gamma}];
   rpyMatInv = Transpose[rpyMat];
   {obliq, georange, lambdadet, phi0, lambda0, R, k0, fe, fn, gamma, 
    omega, rpyMat, rpyMatInv}
   ];


geoProjectionID["AdamsSquareII"] := {"AdamsSquareII", "Spherical"};
DataPaclets`GeoProjectionDataDump`projectionQ["AdamsSquareII"] = True;

(* This projection is periodic. *)
Unprotect[PeriodicProjectionQ];
PeriodicProjectionQ["AdamsSquareII"] := True;
Protect[PeriodicProjectionQ];

AppendTo[DataPaclets`GeoProjectionDataDump`basic, "AdamsSquareII"];
AppendTo[DataPaclets`GeoProjectionDataDump`basicSpherical, "AdamsSquareII"];

(* This projection uses centering. *)
AppendTo[System`GeoGraphicsDump`$projectionsWithCentering, "AdamsSquareII"];

DataPaclets`GeoProjectionDataDump`iGeoProjectionData[] := 
  Evaluate[Append[DataPaclets`GeoProjectionDataDump`iGeoProjectionData[], "AdamsSquareII"]];
DataPaclets`GeoProjectionDataDump`iGeoProjectionData["AdamsSquareII", "Parameters"] = {"Centering" -> {{0, 0}, 0, 0}, 
   "GridOrigin" -> {0, 0}, "ReferenceModel" -> 1};
EndPackage[];
End[];


1 M. Fabreat: Conformal Cartographic Representations (2017).

Oh, right, it should be landColor.

Beautifully done.  Bravissimo!
